# Can I add ‘to come’ after ‘As I promised’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

As I promised, I will certainly come.

Can I add ‘to come’ after ‘As I promised’?

Comment: Do you have a wider context for this sentence? "As I promised to come, ..." makes sense but you need an end to the sentence. You can think of as, as a because in this context.

Comment: I corrected my text. I lost few words before.

Comment: You need to rid yourself of the "to".

Comment: Right, I corrected it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rid yourself of the "to".

> As I promised, I will certainly come.

Slightly more informally, you also don't need the additional I as it is implied already:

> As promised, I will certainly come.

This should help with when to use the "to": https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/verbs-followed-infinitive

"As I promised to come, I will certainly come." also works! I might use "since" or "because" here instead of "as", but it's no big deal. It is is grammatical, but it's poor in terms of style. I would not recommend the repetition.

Comment: How about: As I promised to come, I will certainly come.

Comment: That also works! I might use "since" or "because" here instead of "as", but it's no big deal.

Comment: @Y.zeng That is grammatical, but it's poor in terms of style. I would not recommend the repetition.